# Between two walls

Tags: wordplay, english, connect-wall

For each box, the given words can be divided into **four groups** of four words each, according to some criteria. The names of the resulting categories can in turn be used to find out a final **two-word answer**.

#1

```
acid        alkaline    bath        brain
car         eclipse     hail        hound
lithium     money       panel       pressure
sand        snow        system      wind
```

#2

```
boat        cameral     half        holy
home        hot         lingual     mineral
monthly     oil         pedal       shelf
sea         still       way         wild
```

---

<sub>This puzzle is part of *[Recycling old answers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/81150)*.</sub>

Comment: Are there four different categories for each box?

Comment: @Areeb Yeah, four for the first one and different four for the second one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe that kovacsur has the first box. Borrowing from their answer (thanks, @kovacsur!):

> lithium BATTERY, alkaline BATTERY, BATTERY acid, car BATTERY = **BATTERY** 
>  sandSTORM, snowSTORM, brainSTORM, hailSTORM = **STORM** 
>  
>  BLOOD money, BLOOD pressure, BLOODbath, BLOODhound = **BLOOD** 
>  SOLAR eclipse, SOLAR system, SOLAR panel, SOLAR wind = **SOLAR**

The word I'd associate with all of their found words is

> CELL: blood cell, solar cell, cell battery, storm cell.

Then:

> BIcameral, BImonthly, BIlingual, BIpedal = **BI** 
>  seaWATER, still WATER, holy WATER, mineral WATER = **WATER** (thanks, @kovacsur!) 
>  half LIFE, wildLIFE, LIFEboat, shelf LIFE = **LIFE** (thanks, @kovacsur!) 
>  MOTORhome, hot MOTOR, MOTOR oil, MOTORway = **MOTOR**

This means that the second word is

> CYCLE: biCYCLE, water CYCLE, life CYCLE, and motorCYCLE.

The two words from this puzzle are

> CELL CYCLE, the final answer!

Comment: That sounds reasonable.

Comment: Oh, I was too late, it seems. Well done! :)

Comment: Thank you! Great start on the solving! Good teamwork, @kovacsur :)

Comment: You have the correct answer, although somehow the grouping is a bit different than I intended... I had rot13(fgvyy yvsr, zbgbeobng, naq ubg jngre)! :P

Answer (score 11):

Let's see if I can get the formatting right...

> lithium     alkaline    acid        car         **battery** 
>  sand        snow        brain        hail        **storm** 
>  money       pressure bath        hound       **blood** 
>  eclipse     system      panel       wind     **solar**

That said,

> solar-battery bloodstorm sounds a bit of a stretch, though. 
>  Alright, I am fairly certain that the word for the first box is **plexus**.
>  Update: nope, it is indeed **cell**.

Second box:

> lingual     monthly     cameral      pedal       **bi** 
>  sea         still       holy     mineral     **water** 
>  half        wild     boat        shelf       **life** 
>  home        hot         oil         way         **???**

Still not sure about the last group, but the second word is

> **cycle**

Making the complete solution

> **cell cycle**

Comment: No problem! I think you have the correct four words, you just need to find another word that relates to the four bolded words that you already found. Great start!

Answer (score 3):

Box 1:

> 1. Batteries: car, acid, lithium, alkaline
> 2. Weather: hail, snow, pressure, wind
> 3. Human: system, bath, money, panel
> 4. Nature: sand, hound, eclipse, brain

Unsure about Box 2